# codeigniter linking isn't working properly

Tags: php, css, codeigniter

here is the main controller ( welcome ):

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Welcome extends CI_Controller {


    public function index()
    {
        $this->login();
    }


    public function login()
    {
        $this->load->view("index");
    }

    public function home()
    {
        $this->load->view("home");
    }
```

the index page is working fine it's a login page, but whenever I click on the login button ( which is supposed to take me to the home page ), it loads the home page but without the styling , although the styling is in the same home.php page and the function home works properly as I changed the

```
public function index()
    {
        $this->login();
    }
```

to :

```
 public function index()
    {
        $this->home();
    }
```

just to test it and it works fine with all the styling, still when linking to it it doesn't load the styling,, here's  the login button code :

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/welcome/home"
  class="btn btn-greensea b-0 br-2 mr-5" >  Login</a>
```

anyone can help ?
thanks